# How to make "@Transactional"-like annotation by using AOP without Spring

Tags: jpa, aop

I have a non-Spring application. I want to make an aspect or something like that which should do the code below before and after to make my method or class transactional like Spring's @Transactional annotation;

Before;

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence
        .createEntityManagerFactory("AdvancedMapping");

/* Create EntityManager */
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
EntityTransaction transaction = em.getTransaction();

transaction.begin();
```

After;

```
transaction.commit();
em.close();
```

How can I do this? Where can I find similar tutorials or examples for it?

EDIT:
By the way, it is needed to have em inside of the method which has @Transactional.

```
@Transactional
private int doSomething(String text) {
    // Here I should have the "em" which was already taken in the aspect, 
    // so I can persist something in text
    SomeEntityObject seo = new SomeEntityObject();
    seo.setText(text);
    em.persist(seo);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/). You find tutorials and other documentation [here](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/docs.php). If you build your project with Maven you want to use the [AspectJ Maven plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/) so as to simplify and automate aspect compilation and weaving.

A little example:

**Marker annotation:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Transactional {
    String value();
}
```

**Driver application:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application application = new Application();
        application.doSomething("foo");
        application.doSomethingElse(11);
        application.doSomething("bar");
        application.doSomethingElse(22);
    }

    @Transactional("please wrap me")
    public int doSomething(String text) {
        System.out.println("Doing something with '" + text + "'");
        return 42;
    }

    public void doSomethingElse(int number) {
        System.out.println("Doing something else with number " + number);
    }
}
```

**Transaction wrapper aspect:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;

import de.scrum_master.app.Transactional;

@Aspect
public class TransactionalAspect {
    @Around("execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(transactional)")
    public Object wrapWithTransaction(ProceedingJoinPoint thisJoinPoint, Transactional transactional) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println(thisJoinPoint + " -> " + transactional);
//        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("AdvancedMapping");
//        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
//        EntityTransaction transaction = em.getTransaction();
        try {
            Object result = thisJoinPoint.proceed();
//            transaction.commit();
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
//            transaction.rollback();
            throw e;
        }
        finally {
//            em.close();
        }
    }
}
```

**Console log with JPA stuff commented out:**

```
execution(int de.scrum_master.app.Application.doSomething(String)) -> @de.scrum_master.app.Transactional(value=please wrap me)
Doing something with 'foo'
Doing something else with number 11
execution(int de.scrum_master.app.Application.doSomething(String)) -> @de.scrum_master.app.Transactional(value=please wrap me)
Doing something with 'bar'
Doing something else with number 22
```

Comment: Thank you. How do I get the "em" inside of the method? For this example, in the method doSomething(), I need to "save/update/delete" the entities  by using EntityManager instance.

Comment: I can only tell you if you show me your code. How would you get the entity manager from within the annotated methods? Is it a parameter? Is it `this` or a member of `this`? Basically if I know how you would get it from there, I can tell you how your aspect can get access to it too. But I really recommend you to read an AspectJ introduction.

Comment: Not really. First I thought you want go get the entity manager (EM) from the annotated method into the aspect. Now it looks the other way around, i.e. you want to instantiate the EM in the aspect and then access it from the annotated method, right? That is also possible, but one more question: How many EM instances do you need? One per transaction? One per class with annotated methods? One per application (singleton)? My answer depends on yours.

Answer (score 1):

I am adding another answer beside my original one because there seems to be an alternative to rebuilding `@Transactional` from scratch via AspectJ just so as to avoid using the Spring container:

Actually, declarative transaction support for Spring already ***is*** an AspectJ aspect. The Spring manual describes [how to use `@Transactional` with AspectJ *without* the Spring container](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-aspectj). You do not even need Spring XML configuration but can inject the transaction manager directly into the aspect (code snippet quoted from the manual):

```java
// construct an appropriate transaction manager
DataSourceTransactionManager txManager = new DataSourceTransactionManager(getDataSource());

// configure the AnnotationTransactionAspect to use it;
// this must be done before executing any transactional methods
AnnotationTransactionAspect.aspectOf().setTransactionManager(txManager);
```